Enforcing symmetries "for bag-of-vector" data in XGBoost or random forest - geodata example for illustration
I'll give a concrete toy problem, then give some comments on what sorts of abstractions I care about.
Toy problem: Each person $i$ in my dataset has a phone, and every once in a while the phone will record a location. I then get to see an unordered list of locations $\{ (x^{(i)}_{j}, y^{(i)}_{j}\}_{j=1}^{N}$. I want to learn a classifier that tells me which people belong to a certain recreational soccer league that meets across the city at a few soccer fields. I want to use something like XGBoost to do the classifying.
A few observations:

If I don't restrict myself to generic classifiers like XGBoost, I should be able to learn this sort of classifier from this sort of data. For example, I could look for locations that are common to people in the league but not to people out of the league. So this isn't a case of trying to solve an obviously-impossible problem - I just don't see how to use already-implemented algorithms to solve it.
Out of the box, XGBoost is going to do badly at this, because it doesn't understand that my list of locations is mostly unordered (the ordering of x-coordinates and y-coordinates is meaningful). In particular, I think it should be looking at decision rules along the lines of "does any observation fall near point p," but as-implemented I think that it can only learn decision rules along the lines of "does the observation at index j fall near point p." In principle you can go from the latter to the former, but it is extremely difficult.
If the city is small, I could of course do a one-hot encoding of discretizations of space. I want to avoid this solution, because it won't generalize well to most of the actual problems I care about.

Thanks for any thoughts! Ideally somebody will tell me that somebody has already implemented the sorts of decision rules I mention in (2) - this seems like a pretty generic thing to want to do, it is just the first time I happen to have run into it!
